# Legend text Under and part of graph (winforms) C#

Tags: c#, winforms, graph, legend

Does anyone know how to display the legend text as part of the chart on a winform chart control?
In other words display each legend text under the bar graph as a label, with the text orientated vertically or at an angle. 
I have searched and tried but can’t seem to find the solution to this small problem.
I use linq to sql to query a Database function that gives me the number of inter views per user in a given month. I want to display this data on a graph with the number of interviews on the y axis and the user name on the x axis.
Also is it possible to specify the colors used on the graph series for each data item (user)
Thanks in advance.
[image]

```
        var q = DB.GetNumberOfInterviews(monthStart, monthEnd);

        dgvInterviews.DataSource = q;
        dgvInterviews.Columns["User_ID"].Visible = false;

        foreach (var item in q)
        {
            string strUser = item.FirstName + " " + item.LastName;
            Series series = chrtInterviews.Series.Add(strUser);
            //series.XValueType = ChartValueType.Int32;
            series.YValueType = ChartValueType.Int32;
            series.YValueType = ChartValueType.String;
            series.AxisLabel = "User";
            series.IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
            series.ToolTip = strUser;
            series.Points.Add(item.NumberOfInterviews);
        }
```